# "No ROS_WORKSPACE set" - Problem

Tags: ros, ros-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to use roscd inside of my ros_workspace, without typing:

> source ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash

at first. In this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays) is written:

> It is very common to replace the line
> source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash to
> source the setup.bash in
> ~/fuerte_workspace.

I suspect that this sentence is the solution.
Due to English is not my Motherlanguage I just dont get it what to do in order to use roscd instantly for all packages inside of my fuerte_workspace.

Can someone please give me an exact instruction to reach my goal?

Thanks in advance
Dominik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46869/%22no-ros_workspace-set%22---problem/) by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2012-10-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, hopefully this helps you out.

From my personal experience (on Ubuntu) I've found that adding the following lines to my ~/.bashrc file keeps everything for me in working condition:

```
source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
export ROS_WORKSPACE=~/ros_workspace
```

and in your case I think you would want it to be:

```
source ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/fuerte_workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
export ROS_WORKSPACE=~/fuerte_workspace
```

That should let you use roscd and other ros command line tools with your setup.

---

Originally posted by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) with karma: 549 on 2012-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on 2012-10-26**:
Did you meant the bash.bashrc file under /etc? Because I found 3 aditional files with bashrc in it. I could change this file (under /etc) only with root-permissions. But after modifying the file nothing changed.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2012-10-26**:
It should not be necessary to set ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or ROS_WORKSPACE in your .bashrc. Try only "source ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash", this should work as well.

**Comment by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on 2012-10-26**:
Exactly this is the problem. I don't want to type this line everytime in a new console when i want to roscd a package out of my workspace. I know it must be possible (in another vmware image it is like that).

**Comment by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) on 2012-10-27**:
I think what KruseT was saying is that you don't need all the lines I put in there. Only the first. This goes in the file .bashrc in your user's home directory, which is what the prefix ~ means. Every time you open a new terminal, that will be loaded and you won't need to type it.